# Double tap on UWP usercontrol removes focus

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a simple user control and I would like to double click it to execute an action.
The double-tapped event is triggered, and the focus moves to my control but directly after that the focus switches to the RootScrollViewer in the Visual Tree instead of staying on my control. When I single click it stays on my control.

Here is my control:

```
...
DoubleTapped="UserControl_DoubleTapped"
Tapped="UserControl_Tapped"
IsDoubleTapEnabled="True"
IsTapEnabled="True"
AllowFocusOnInteraction="True"
TabIndex="0"
IsTabStop="True" >

<Grid Background="Gray" BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="10">
    <TextBlock Text="Hello World" FontSize="48" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

And here is the code behind:

```
private void UserControl_DoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //execute some action

    //trying to set back focus here but not working
    this.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
}

//I use this to focus:
private void UserControl_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
}
```

Why does the focus get moved to the RootScrollViewer every time I double click the Textblock in my control?

[image]

As you can see in the video, at first I double click, so the focus moves to my control and afterwards to the RootScrollViewer. At the end of the video I single click and the focus stays on the control

[image]

Edit:
https://github.com/FrozenAssassine/UserControlFocusIssue

Comment: I did some tests and did not reproduce your problem. Could you provide a code snippet of ScrollViewer or a sample that can reproduce the problem? By the way, which device is your program running on, is this laptop?

Comment: I have tested it on both my Pc and my Laptop, and neither is working. I have also added a video visualizing the problem

Comment: Could you please share a code snippet of your ScrollViewer?

Comment: The Scrollviewer isn't added by me. It is default in all UWP windows. I have added a picture of the live visual tree. All I have in my MainPage is a Grid containing my UserControl.

Comment: You can try putting your usercontrol into <ContentControl>.

Comment: Same behavior when double clicking

Comment: I still can't reproduce your problem with the code you provided so far, could you please provide the complete MainPage.xaml code so that we can troubleshoot for you.

Comment: I have updated my question with a github link

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5ERW.png  I download your project and tested on two computers, neither has RootScrollViewer in visual tree. My test environment is Win11 22H2 OS build 22621.963.

Comment: What happens when you disable the Button "Show just my xaml" (in the live visual tree) and track the focus in the Visual Tree. Will the focus switch on double click?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I reproduced it successfully, I will discuss with the team if this is an expected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way to fix this issue:

```
private void ContentControl_LosingFocus(UIElement sender, LosingFocusEventArgs args)
{
    //When the focus wants to move to the rootScrollViewer -> prevent it
    if(args.NewFocusedElement is ScrollViewer sv && sv.Content is Border)
    {
        args.TryCancel();
    }
}
```

This function cancels the focus switching only if the next control is a scrollviewer and inside the scrollviewer is a border. Why Scrollviewer and Border? Because the RootScrollViewer is a ScrollViewer and has a Border as its content.

Currently this is the only way to prevent the focus removing, when I double click on a control